# Conditional expectation on X of conditional expectation on a function of X

Tags: conditional-expectation

Sorry if the title is confusing.
I am studying this property:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(Y|W)|X] = \mathbb E[Y|X] 
$$
where $X=f(W)$,
and I don't really know if I am proving it right.

Here's my proof:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(Y|W)|X] 
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_\mathbb R y \frac{f_{WXY}(w,x,y)} {f_{WX}(w,x)} dy \big|X \right]\\
&=\int_\mathbb R\int_\mathbb R y \frac{f_{WXY}(w,x,y)} {f_{WX}(w,x)} dy 
    \frac {f_{WX}(w,x)} {f_X(x)} dw \\
\end{align}
$$
and so the $f_{WX}$'s cancel out and we have
$$
\begin{align}
&=\int_\mathbb R\int_\mathbb R y \frac{f_{WXY}}{f_X}dydw = \int_\mathbb R y\frac{f_{XY}}{f_X}dy=\mathbb E(Y|X)
\end{align}
$$
Am I getting anything wrong here?
What makes me unsure about my proof is the first step, i.e. writing
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y|W) = \int_\mathbb R y \frac{f_{WXY}(w,x,y)} {f_{WX}(w,x)} dy
$$
But I am not able to prove it otherwise.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of working with probability densites, which don't have to exist in the first place (and I don't see what kind of definition of conditional expectations you are using, even if they exist), you could go to the defining property of conditional expectations. The basic idea is: Since the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f(W)$ is coarser than the one generated by $W$, you obtain the same object whether you first condition on the finer $\sigma$-algebra and then on the coarser one, or on the coarser $\sigma$-algebra directly.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to apply the definition of conditional expectation:
\begin{gather*}
E\biggl[E\Bigl[E\big[Y\mid W\big]\Big| X\Bigr]I_A(X)\biggr]=
E\Bigl[E\big[Y\mid W\big]I_A(X)\Bigr]=\\
=E\Bigl[E\big[Y\mid W\big]I_A(f(W))\Bigr]=
E\Bigl[E\big[Y\mid W\big]I_{f^{-1}(A)}(W)\Bigr]=\\
=E\big[YI_{f^{-1}(A)}(W)\big]=E\big[YI_A(f(W)\big]=E\big[YI_A(X)\big]
\end{gather*}

Comment: The indicator function. $I_A(X(\omega))=1$ if $X(\omega)\in A$,  $0$ otherwise.